# How to fix neutralino white screen?

Tags: javascript, node.js, neutralinojs

I created a blank **neutralino js** application and when I turn it on using the neu run command, a white screen is displayed. I used the `CheckNetIsolation.exe ...` command and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your have visual studio installed

or just run the command in powershell as admin

```
CheckNetIsolation.exe LoopbackExempt -a -n="Microsoft.Win32WebViewHost_cw5n1h2txyewy"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to start CMD in admin mode to execute that command (right click on cmd.exe and choose run as administrator).

Answer (score 0):

Both VSCode and cmd are configured to run as Adminstrator and running CheckNetIsolation returns OK but changes nothing.

neu run still opens a white screen

Windows 10 Pro x64
Neutralinojs binaries: v3.0.0
Neutralinojs client: v2.0.0
neu CLI: v7.0.0

neu build works and I can launch the "myApp" executable for windows but I cannot get anything else processed. No javascript. Only HTML and CSS.

Very frustrated with NeutralinoJS