# How to code neutralinoJS to move the window to 0,0?

Tags: neutralinojs

Clueless dude here that does not get any results with anything in neutralino except HTML and CSS mods.

I have to neu build because CheckNetIsolation does nothing on my x64 Windows 10 Pro machine. So I can run the "myApp" executable. While that's annoying my real problem is I can't get any js code to produce results.

For example I enter Neutralino.window.move(0,0); immediately before Neutralino.init(); in VSCode. The window opens and remains in its default location.

What's my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Check your `neutralino.config.json` file. In the latest version of Neutralino, `enableHTTPServer` has been replaced with just `enableServer`.

My Neu App remained while as well, until I did that.

[Also, ensure that you have VSCode installed.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68414141/3230399)

Finally, according to the [documentation (scroll down to DANGER)](https://neutralino.js.org/docs/api/init):

> Aways use the `ready` event to call native API functions immediately. Don't call native API functions before the `init()` call or right after the `init()` call because the `init()` function doesn't synchronously wait until the WebSocket connection is established.

You need to call `Neutralino.init()` **before** any other functions, and since you need to move the window immediately, place it within the ready event:

```js
Neutralino.init();

Neutralino.events.on('ready', () => {
    Neutralino.window.move(0, 0);
});
```

I hope all this helps.